# TestCafe - Select option in <select>

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a `<select>` with several `<option>` tags. Some of them are disabled by using the class 'is-disabled'. What I want to do is select the first available option in the list. For this, I used an example that I found on the testcafe website (https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/testing-select-elements.html) but I can't seem to get it to work.

When running the test, the tool performs a click on the select and a second one after which it closes. After this, no value is selected.

Is there a better way to handle the dynamic selection of an option? Or what would be a better solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

regards
Cornel

```
SizeSelector component:

import {t, Selector} from 'testcafe';

class SizeSelector {

  constructor() {
    this._sizeSelector = Selector('.sizeSelectionGroup');
    this._selectors = this._sizeSelector.child('.productSizeSelection');
    this._widthSelector = this._selectors.nth(0);

    // todo other size types (single numeric/text)
  }

  // todo refactor
  async setFirstAvailableWidth() {
    const options = this._widthSelector.find('option'); // contains 13 elements while debugging
    const availableOptions = options.filter(node => {
      return !node.classList.contains('is-disabled');
    });

    const count = await availableOptions.count; // contains around 8 elements while debugging
    if (count > 0) {
      return await t
        .click(this._widthSelector)
        .click(availableOptions.nth(0))
        .expect(this._lengthSelector.value).ok(); // fails with value undefined
    }

    throw new Error('No available width found.');
  }
}

export default SizeSelector;
```

Comment: this may be a typo, but I'm not seeing _lengthSelector actually defined. I do see you have _widthSelector defined in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I am not sure if this will work for you exactly in your situation. I tried to simulate a dropdown which had several options using the class **'is-disabled'** and made a test with a function that will click the very first option in the dropdown that is not disabled I based the function off [this](https://github.com/hdorgeval/testcafe-snippets#tc-select-first-non-empty-option)

**Here is the example dropdown I made**

https://jsfiddle.net/L6p2u/190/

**Here is the test code (Orange should be the first option that isn't disabled)**

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';

fixture `testcafe canvas`
    .page `https://jsfiddle.net/L6p2u/190/`;

const medwait            = 5000
const longwait           = 15000;
const dropdown           = Selector('#colour');

async function selectFirstAvailableOption(selector) {
    const select = selector;
    await t // select the first available option
        .setTestSpeed(0.7)
        .hover(select)
        .expect(select.hasAttribute("disabled")).notOk({timeout: 5000})
        .click(select)
        .click(select
            .find("option")
            .filter((node) => {
                if (node && node.className.indexOf('is-disabled') == -1) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            })
            .nth(0)).wait(5000); // this wait is just so you can see
}

test('Instructor', async t => {
    await t
        .switchToIframe('[name="result"]')
    await selectFirstAvailableOption(dropdown);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With that solution, you can avoid ".setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)" call, when you interatc with dropdown.

```js
export async function create(name) {
  const dropdown = await Selector("#dropDownID");
  const dropdownOption = dropdown.find("option");

  await t
    .click(dropdown)
    .click(dropdownOption.withText(name))
    .click(Selector("#submitBtn"));
}
```